# Wildfly modules

Tags: primefaces, wildfly, jboss-modules

I'm trying to move primefaces on wildfly server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="by.lib">  
        <resources>  
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar"/>  
        <resource-root path="primefaces-6.0.jar"/>  
        <resource-root path="commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar"/>  
    </resources> 
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" /> 
        <module name="javax.faces.api" />
        <module name="javax.el.api" />
    </dependencies> 
</module>
```

What else depending on me for?

I have error such error

```
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56) javax.el.ELException: Function 'p:component' not found
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:275)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:172)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:227)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:238)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:295)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:112)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.apply(ELText.java:211)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.apply(ELText.java:188)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.apply(AttributeInstruction.java:101)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructionHandler.apply(UIInstructionHandler.java:142)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
10:35:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
10:35:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at com.github.zhanhb.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:55)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.faces.UrlFilter.doFilter(UrlFilter.java:118)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
10:35:40,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
10:35:40,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
10:35:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-56)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:35:40,026 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-56) Function 'p:component' not found: javax.el.ELException: Function 'p:component' not found
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:172)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:238)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:295)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.apply(ELText.java:211)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.apply(ELText.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.apply(AttributeInstruction.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructionHandler.apply(UIInstructionHandler.java:142)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.github.zhanhb.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.faces.UrlFilter.doFilter(UrlFilter.java:118)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

All work fine

And the last question
Did I understand correctly in modules.xml

Resources - there are written libraries that are not in WildFly. 
Dependencies - then the path to the libraries of WildFly

Answer (score 0):

Even when you install any library as a module. you need to include it in your maven project to be compiled locally.

But you need to change the scope from compile to provided.Because with provided scope, maven will not package the jar files with .war file; instead wildfly will load the module from the server.

Try to change the scope to provided. If it works, then you installed the module correctly, otherwise check the next error.

Comment: In in my project scope - provied.

Answer (score 0):

I add **meta-inf="export"** to my jboss-deployment-structure.xml and all work fine